# Possible to completely deactivate a RigidBody 2D component so that the Composite Collider on a parent object works?

Tags: unity, collider

In my Unity game, I have two GameObjects with the tag "Animal": Snake and Tiger, nested like so:.

> Snake
>
> > Tiger

I have a Composite Collider 2D/RigidBody 2D on both the parent GameObject (Snake), and the child GameObject (Tiger).  They conflict with each other, so that the Snake GameObject isn't able to detect the colliders in Tiger.

I need to disable both the Composite Collider 2D and RigidBody 2D components on the child Snake.

The most straightforward way to do this is to completely delete both Components from the child, which makes Snake's Composite Collider work perfectly.

That said, the Components are custom configured and I'd love to disable them without having to delete them.

I was able to disable the Composite Collider 2D component with a script, but couldn't find a way to completely disable the RigidBody 2D Component.   As an attempt at a workaround, I set the RigidBody 2D's behavior to Static... but that didn't work (when I did that, the Snake's Composite Collider wasn't picking up the child properly).

Is there another way to disable a RigidBody 2D, such that a parent Composite Collider will work?  Or is the only option to completely delete it - and if I need it later, to then Add the Component back and then configure any settings using scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: To understand it, why is the Tiger a child of the snake? With better understanding what you want to achieve, it might be that you have a XY problem and overcomplicate it

Comment: It's a word game and letters can  be combined.  Nesting them makes positioning them much easier, and helps with drag and drop too.

Comment: Just wondering if there are any other ways to disable the Rigidbody 2D... if not I will Add Component and then add the setting back with code.